# Error in creating an auth0-lock dialog

Tags: auth0

I'm a very new in Auth0 and want to write a javascript code to show Auth0 login/signup dialog. I installed Auth0 and auth0-lock by `npm install auth0 auth0-lock --save` and have the related package.json file. I started coding by these two lines:

```
     var Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock')
     var lock = new Auth0Lock([my client ID], [my domain], {});
     lock.show();
```

Now,when I run this piece of code, I get the following error:

```
     TypeError: Auth0Lock is not a constructor
```

Would you please help me to fix this error and do you have a clean javascript code to create a auth0 dialog for user login?

Answer (score 0):

Helpful to indicate the version of Lock that you are using.

[Here is a Sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-regular-webapp-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/views/login.pug) using Lock 11 (latest version) embedded within webpage.

This just uses a [CDN link](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-regular-webapp-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/views/layout.pug#L8)

If you are using a npm module, then presumably you have a JS build process (webpack, browserify etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var lockJs = require('auth0-lock');
var lock = new lockJs.Auth0Lock([my client ID], [my domain], {});
lock.show();
```